# Laravel + Vue npm run watch\dev suddently freezes while building modules

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix

I'm having some issues while working with Laravel and Vue using npm (laravel mix), everything was working fine until some point where `npm run watch` or `npm run build` just dont complete the building and freezes, I've tried to let it load for about an hour but nothing is happening.

I'm on a Windows 10 Server 2012 R2 machine, I've installed nodejs and npm from the official website using the installer, worked on a project for a couple of days without any issue.

My npm version is 6.4.1, node version is 10.15.3, I don't think it's a problem of compatibility since everything just worked fine until now.

I've tried verifying the cache, deleting node_modules and reinstalling the packages, disabling the default notifications on laravel mix, still nothing. Here's a screen of the cmd at the point of the freeze:

[image: npm freeze window]

Any idea what could be the problem and solution?

**EDIT:** Ok, apparently, there was some error which npm wouldn't tell me about and just straight freeze. I copied everything on Linux and tried from there, found the errors, fixed them on windows and npm got back to working fine. But that's still very weird, why couldn't it just show me the errors like on unix? It's kinda useless if everytimes something like this happens I have to copy everything in another place in order to know what's wrong.

Comment: Does it "unfreeze" back after some time?

Comment: @Tarasovych nope, as I said, I've left it loading hoping for unfreeze for about an hour.